# Check that an exception is correctly raised in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, exception, python-unittest

Does anyone know how to check that an exception is raised correctly?

I need something that works in Python 2.7. The below 'assert' is not quite correct method to use from the Python unittest library:

```
assert ( a_a0_getinst.add_port("iTCK", ISC.PortType_INPUT) ), "Can't add duplicate port"
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_010_module.py", line 157, in runTest
    a_a0_addinst = a_a0.add_instance( "A00", b_a0 )
  File "/nfs/sc/disks/sc_dteg_2004/users/acheung1/dteg_tools-isc/python/t/ISC.py", line 475, in add_instance
    return _ISC.SharedModule_add_instance(self, name, module)
RuntimeError: Can't add duplicate instance with instance name 'A00' to module 'A_A0'
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to make sure it raises the *correct type of exception*, you can use:

```
self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, your_function, *args, **kwargs)
```

in a unittest.TestCase class. See [the docs for assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

If you also want to check that it also has the *correct error message*, you can instead use:

```
self.assertRaisesRegexp(RuntimeError, "error message", your_function_call, *args, **kwargs)
```

in a unittest.TestCase class. Here are [the docs for assertRaisesRegexp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp).

You can also do these as context managers, in which case you don't need to separate the arguments out:

```
with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
    your_function_call(arg1, arg2)

with self.assertRaisesRegexp(RuntimeError, "error message"):
    your_function_call(arg1, arg2)
```

Those are for Python 2.7, as you mentioned. For Python 3.x, `assertRaises` behaves the same, but the regular expression one is called `assertRegex` (no `p`).

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this only works if you're using unittest-style test classes. If you're using py.test, [it has its own similar methods you can use](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions).

Comment: Thanks, bouteillebleu!

I did this:

     self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, a_a0.add_instance( "A00", b_a0 ))

...but I'm still getting that same error as aforementioned in the problem statement.

Comment: Also tried "self.assertRaisesRegexp(RuntimeError, "Can't add duplicate instance with instance name 'A00' to module 'A_A0'", a_a0.add_instance( "A00", b
    _a0 ))" with error:

Traceback (most ... last):
  File "test_010_module.py", line 157, in runTest
    self.assertRaisesRegexp(RuntimeError, "Can't add duplicate instance with instance name 'A00' to module 'A_A0'", a_a0.add_instance( "A00", b_a0 ))
  File "xxx", line x, in add_instance
    return _ISC.SharedModule_add_instance(self, name, module)
RuntimeError: Can't add duplicate instance with instance name 'A00' to module 'A_A0

Comment: Ah, I've reread the 2.7 docs and it looks like the syntax is different there from 3.x - I'll correct my answer! You have to pass the arguments separately from the function, it looks like.

Comment: I had another look and it was my mistake - if you're just running `self.assertRaises()` or `self.assertRaisesRegexp()` as a statement, you have to pass the arguments in separately. But if you use `with` to have it as a context manager, you can just call the function as you normally would. Edited the answer to correct that!

Comment: Any luck with this with the changes?

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you, bouteillebleu :)